# Unable to click the button with Selenium RC using CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, selenium-rc, selenium-chromedriver, xpath

I'm unable to click the button using CSS in Selenium RC with c# as programming language although the code focuses and highlights the button using CSS. Here's my code.

```
   if(selenium.IsElementPresent("css=button[id$=searchButton]"))  //finds the button               
   {                                                                  
   selenium.Focus("css=button[id$=searchButton]"); // focuses the button                       
   selenium.Highlight("css=button[id$=searchButton]");     //highlights the button                       
   selenium.Click("css=button[id$=searchButton]");      //doesn't click the button???      
   }
```

The Xpath code below works perfectly fine in Selenium RC with C#.

```
   selenium.Click("xpath=//button[matches(@id,'.*searchButton')]"); //works fine with this xpath code
```

Here's the HTML code for the button.

```
<td align="left" style= "vertical-align : top;">
<button type="button" class="ClassButton" id="genId_38_:mainPanel_genId_39:searchButton"  tabindex="0">
Click Me</button>
</td>
```

Any little bit of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
selenium.Click("css=button[id$='searchButton']");
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
selenium.InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your reply. Where do you put the id of the css code in selenium.InvokeMember("click") though??

Comment: Well you don't need any css changes on click right, You just need it to trigger the action?

Comment: I'm not sure how you trigger the action with your code. When i put selenium.InvokeMember("css code"), it says the selenium doesn't contain a definition for 'InvokeMember'. Can you please explain it more clearly? Thanks- Ash